# Can't remove old Docker Networking Settings

Tags: linux, docker, networking, docker-command

I hope you can help.

I had an old docker image that was configured for networking exposing port 8082. I am using this image as my base image to created a new container but I can't seem to get rid of the old networking settings.
The 8082 ports are not specified in my new Dockerfile or docker-composer file but it still comes up. My new port is 8091.

```
server@omv:~/docker/app$ docker container ls
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE              COMMAND            CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                                NAMES
f023f6a0a792   api_app_image   "/entrypoint.sh"   3 minutes ago   Up 3 minutes   80/tcp, 8082/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8091->8091/tcp   api_app
```

Here is my docker-composer file.

```
api_app:
     container_name: api_app
     build:
      context: ./api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
     ports:
     - "8091:8091"
     volumes:
     - ./api/app:/var/www/html/apiapp
```

Here is a snip from my Dockerfile

```
FROM bde8c3167970 

VOLUME /etc/nginx/conf.d

VOLUME /var/www/html/apiapp

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]


EXPOSE 80 8091
```

Thanks, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If I understood your correctly, you only need to stop and destroy that container.

Comment: It's derived from a base image with those ports,  so stopping and destroying the container won't help unfortunately. When I start up the container , I will have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Dockerfile option to remove a port that's been set with [`EXPOSE`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose), and it is always [inherited by derived images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57577265/which-dockerfile-instructions-are-inherited-in-deriving-images); you can't remove this value.

However:

1. In modern Docker simply having a port "exposed" (as distinct from "published") means almost nothing.  It shows up in the `docker ps` output as unmapped, and if you use the `docker run -P` option to publish all exposed ports, it will be assigned an arbitrary host port, but that's it.  There's no harm to having extra ports exposed.
2. Since each container runs in an isolated network namespace, there's no harm in using the same port in multiple containers.  The container port doesn't have to match the host port.  If the base image expected to run the application on port 8082, I'd keep doing that in the derived image; in the Compose setup, you can set `ports: ['8091:8082']` to pick a different host port.

Comment: Thanks @david, I guess that is true regarding your point number 2. It's just nice to have the ports match up.  Regarding point 1. When you say it's "unmapped" would the output  "8082/tcp" be unmapped and the output  "0.0.0.0:8091->8091/tcp" mean mapped? tx